# QM the superposition principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In [Zetilli's](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8514649-quantum-mechanics) book author says that we can interpret an inner product $\langle x | \psi(t) \rangle$ as a wave function $\psi (x,t)$ and i understand this.

Next he talks about how a state of the system $|\psi(t)\rangle$ can also be represented by a superposition of wave functions which he writes like this:

$$\underbrace{|\psi\rangle}_{\llap{\text{Where is a time dependancy?}}} = \sum_i a_i |\psi_i\rangle$$

**Q1:** I don't understand this. Where did the time dependancy go? Should i write it like this:

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_i a_i |\psi_i(t)\rangle$$

**Q2:** The vectors $|\psi_i (t)\rangle$ aren't the eigenvectors right? I don't know how i can connect this to an eigen equation...

Answer (score 3):

**A1:** Yes,you are right. He means to include the time dependace into |ψi⟩ itself. That is; |ψi⟩ denotes |ψi(t)⟩ is understood.

**A2:** Why are they not? You mean eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian, right?
Then, just apply the Hamiltonian operator on your |ψi(t)⟩, (which means taking a derivative of |ψi(t)⟩). The time dependance is in the exponent, so |ψi(t)⟩ will remain unharmed.

Comment: Tell me if you need me to elaborate the last bit. Try it once, its simple

Answer (score 2):

First things first,

You can expand a state $|\psi\rangle$ from a Hilber Space as a linear conbination of its base, and an ussually good base are the eigensates of an Hermitian Operator, as the Hamiltonian. We will denote them as $|\psi_i\rangle$.

If we solve the Schrödinger equation for the eigenstates (and time independent Hamiltonian):

$$
i\hbar \partial_t |\phi_i\rangle = \hat{H}|\phi_i\rangle = E_i|\phi_i\rangle
$$

you get that the time dependence of every eigenstate is in a phase-factor $e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}$, and as the Hamiltonian and the time derivative are linear, qhen you expand your state, the time dependence is in the time evolution of  every eigenstate:

$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \sum_i a_i |\psi_i(t)\rangle = \sum_i a_i e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}|\psi_i\rangle
$$

Ansering the questions:

** Q 1**: Is only mater of notattion, you can name your state as you wish, you could name it *smiley face*, but ussually is clearer if you stic to conventions

** Q 2**: Yes they are eigenstates, if your Hamiltonian is time independent:

$$
\hat{H} |\psi_i(t)\rangle = \hat{H} e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}|\psi_i\rangle = e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}\hat{H}|\psi_i\rangle = e^{-i\frac{E_i}{\hbar}t}E_i|\psi_i\rangle =  E_i|\psi_i(t)\rangle
$$

Comment: +1 However, you forgot to include time in the exponential. Also note that you can include the time evolution $\exp(-iE_it/\hbar)$ in the coefficients in the expansion which is something I'm used to seeing more often.

Comment: My answer says the same thing! :P